# How can an iOS app reconnect to a background download if the user relaunches the app while the download is occurring?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

iOS 7 introduced the ability to run downloads in the background if an app is terminated. Apple documentation and available examples provide information about how to respond to events triggered by these background downloads so that the download can complete in the background, ready for the user to get access to the downloaded resource when they restart the app.

However, the documentation and examples do not appear to provide information about how to handle the case where an app begins a background transfer, is terminated, but then is restarted by the user before the background transfer has ended. If an app needs to provide the user with information that a background transfer is ongoing but not finished, how can that state be detected and how can the app get progress updates on the background transfer to keep the user informed about how the background download is going?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new background session with an identical identifier, iOS is smart enough to recreate the relevant connections for you.  It 'knows' the 'new' background session is, in fact, a resumption of the old one, and will give you the old one back.

From there, you remain responsible for configuring delegates and other aspects of your personal code (re-)using the session.

Comment: When I try to create a new background session with the same identifier I am getting following error

A background URLSession with identifier "sessionName" already exists!

Comment: @PeerMohamedThabib then you've already recreated it somewhere else.

Comment: Yes I have created the session already. When the download is in progress and I put the app in background while the download is still in progress, I am trying to bring the app from background to foreground. The problem is I am not able to get the progress for the background download once the download is complete thats when I am able to see the progress changes to complete(1.0). Any idea how we can solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PeerMohamedThabib if the app hasn't closed, you don't need to recreate the session.  You only need to recreate the session if the app was closed, not just backgrounded.

Comment: Okay. Is there any way i can get the progress of the background download? E.g: I start a download (100 MB file) I put the app in background by pressing home button. I am bringing the app to foreground but I am not able to track the progress. Once the download completes NSURLSession notifies via URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession: delegate method.
is there any way we can track the progress as soon as we bring the app to fore ground?

Comment: @PeerMohamedThabib You'll want to hook up the URLSessionDownloadDelegate callbacks somewhere.  Look for `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)`

Answer (score 1):

As I'm aware background session has an identifier so I think you can resume it by that identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What do I pass that identifier to so that I can retrieve the session? Looking at [Apple's background execution guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), the section on downloading content in the background suggests that the system automatically reconnects the session recreated in the`application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` delegate method to its previous tasks. It is not clear that will work generally though.

Comment: I cannot prove that the given answer is correct without being able to test background downloading, as discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827050/on-ios-7-how-to-force-a-download-operation-to-be-run-by-the-system-rather-than)